# Old orthography всѣ, все, всё and издалека vs издалёка

Tags: значения, история-языка, правописание, орфография, буква-ё

It's redundant to write the two dots above the е in the word все in old orthography (because when it isnt a ё sound, ѣ is written), so why do some old russian bibles do it still? Some places they write все (which is always всё) and всё (even though its already obvious that it should be pronounced vsyo) is there a semantic, or other reason that changes the meaning behind it?

(1902 изданіе шестое)
Всё - псаломъ 118:91, Екклес. 6:6, few others

Compare to все - бытіе 2:1, (over 800 occurances, very common)

Another interesting thing with ё, in the word издалека, which I have only ever heard pronounced издалека', sometimes can be found with ё - издалёка. I cant find anything on there being a difference in meaning, but here are examples anyway

Издалека - аввакумъ 1:8, марк 5:6

Издалёка - бытіе 22:4, исаія 43:6, 49:12

I think that издалека may have had two ways to pronounce it, and maybe the всё usage was just because they didnt have enough "е"s or something to print with but idk, i want to know if there is for sure no meaning or semantic difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of *e* vs *ё* is not consistent in this edition of the Bible.

In all your examples, the words *издалека* and *издалёка* mean the same ("from far away"), as well as the words *все* and *всё* ("all" in singular neuter).

Other editions of the Synodal translation I could find online don't use *ё* at all.